# Delete all rows that do not contain specific text : Define search range using InStr(Range)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete any row that does not contain a specific text (Federation). The term may be in numerous columns, and may be prefaced by either LOI-, COC- or REA- (i.e. LOI-Federation).
My range of columns has the error

> Method of 'Range' of Object'_Global' Failed

I want to search column O through column IH.

```
Sub CYJLMasterReportMacro()
    SeparateDesignation ("Federation")
End Sub

Sub SeparateDesignation(ByVal DesignationName As String)

    Worksheets.Add().Name = DesignationName
    Worksheets("Results").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
    Worksheets(DesignationName).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 743 To 2 Step -1
        If InStr(Range("O:IH" & i), DesignationName) = 0 Then
            Range("O:IH" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("O:IH" & i)` is not a valid range    `Range("O" & i & ":IH" & i)` should be OK

Comment: I got Type Mismatch when i tried it

Comment: Sorry I missed that - you cannot call InStr() on a multi-cell range.  You'd need to use (eg) `Find`

Comment: what would that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Find`:

```
Sub SeparateDesignation(ByVal DesignationName As String)

    Dim f As Range, i As Long, wsNew as Worksheet

    Worksheets("Results").Copy After:= Worksheets("Results")
    Set wsNew = Worksheets(Worksheets("Results").Index + 1)
    wsNew.Name = DesignationName

    For i = 743 To 2 Step -1
        Set f = nothing
        Set f = wsNew.Range("O" & i & ":IH" & i).Find(DesignationName, lookat:=xlPart)
        If f is nothing Then
            wsNew.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: the reason i have it set as two different Subs is because ultimately there will be many different Designation Names i will be looking for and will want a new sheet for each one then to search or each name and delete all other rows.  Sub CYJLMasterReportMacro() SeparateDesignation ("Federation") SeperateDesignation ("Hillel") Etc

Comment: Not sure what you're referencing?  I only posted one sub because that's the only one which needs to change - it still has a parameter for "designation"

Comment: Oh, Let me try it out

Comment: Syntax Error on Set f = wsNew.Range("O" & i & ":IH" & i).Find(DesignationName, lookat:xlPart)

Comment: Typo `lookat:=xlPart`